# Anchor tag issue in Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, anchor

I have an HTML file which contains anchor tag with the link to another HTML file.
When I click on the link in firefox, its not opening the other HTML file. Please refer the below HTML snippet:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table align=left border=1>
        <tr><th>Report Name</th></tr>
        <tr><td><a href="G:\parent directory\Report\Forms Report Summary_2015-08-25 102050.html" target=report_page>Missing Forms Report</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The issue is that when the link  in "href" is clicked and opened in new Firefox window inseted of "G" (capital letter) "g"(small letter) is displayed in Firefox and I get error page not displayed. I am strugggling to understand why Firefox is taking the "G" in caps as small letter "g". 
Can someone please help me out here?

However, when I open the same link in Chrome or IE its opening fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specifications of anchors expect a valid uri with a protocol as href:
i.e `file`, `ftp`, and `mailto` or an url fragment `#`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href

In your example it think you need the `file`

This should work in your case: (check also to escape it, some browsers do strange different things)

`<a href="file:///G:\parent directory\Report\Forms Report Summary_2015-08-25 102050.html" target=report_page>Missing Forms Report</a>`

Comment: He will probably also need to escape his backslashes.

Comment: This worked for me ! Without escaping the backslashes it worked just fine.